# How do you manage permissions when developing in a Docker container?

Tags: linux, permissions, docker

When developing in a Docker container on Linux, there is a problem with permissions: how to manage file ownership and permissions between the host and the container.

Imagine that I have a Docker image that runs Ubuntu and an Apache server. Using the default settings for (recent versions of) Apache, the document root will be `/var/www/html` and Apache will be run as the `www-data` user.

In order to do some development, I expose the document root via Docker with `-v /path/to/my/files:/var/www/html`. And this is where the problem arises:

The files in `/path/to/my/files` are owned by the containers `www-data` user. If I'm lucky and my host has a `www-data` user, it will be that user; otherwise, it will be a distinct user local to the container. The permissions on those files will (probably) be `0755`.

So, when I'm working away as myself (a user called `jsmith`), those files cannot be edited by me because of incorrect file permissions & ownership.

- I could change the ownership of the files to `jsmith`, but that will cause problems with Apache - it will have difficulty accessing files in the document root.
- I could change the permissions to `0777`, but any new files I create in the course of my work will be owned by `jsmith`.

The end result is that it is necessary to constantly adjust ownership & permissions on the development files. Other people must have this problem, but every post I've seen on the topic of using Docker in a development workflow just kind of overlooks this problem.

I *do* have a solution, but I'm not entirely happy with it:

- I set up a folder at `/src/myproject`. This holds my development files and is owned by `www-data:www-data`.
- Using [BindFS](http://bindfs.org/), I mount `/src/myproject` at `~/myproject`, mapping `www-data:www-data` to `jsmith:jsmith`. This allows me to edit files in `~/myproject` without messing around with permissions.
- The Apache Docker container mounts the `/src/myproject` directory with `-v /src/myproject:/var/www/html`. Apache sees the `www-data` ownership of the files and has no problems.

This works well, but seems overly complicated. How do other people solve this problem?

Comment: Did you find any other method to fix premissions issue?

Comment: Sorry I don't have any suggestions.  I came here looking for the same answer - your BindFS tip was helpful for me.

Comment: Maybe the [lebokus/docker-volume-bindfs ](https://github.com/lebokus/docker-volume-bindfs) will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I realize I'm very likely too late but this might be of help to someone.

In your Dockerfile, you could do this:

```
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data
RUN groupmod -g 1000 www-data
```

This may work in some setups.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two solutions:

Use a common group id among all developers and images. The uid may end up being numeric in the container, but the gid would give at least read access, and optionally write access, without giving it out globally. Use the setgid bit on the containing directories to have files automatically created with this gid. This isn't the cleanest approach, and may lead to giving out access to other group members, but it may be much easier to manage depending on your organization's workflow.

The second option is named volumes, which I believe were added after you asked this question. They let you have the data exist with the uid/gid's known to the containers. This has the downside of moving the data into the internal docker directories where it's less easy to manage outside of a container. However, there are microservices approaches that keep the volume synchronized with an outside source (git pull, rsync, etc) using a dedicated container that mounts the same volume. You essentially move all of the reads and writes of the data into containers, including any backups, update routines, and testing scripts.

---

Update: A third option I often use for development environments is a run an entrypoint script as root that compares the mounted volume uid/gid to the uid/gid of a user inside the container. If they do not match, the uid/gid of the user inside the container is updated to match the host. This allows developers to reuse the same image across multiple hosts where the uid/gid of each developer may be different on their location machine. The code to do this is included in my `bin/fix-perms` script that is part of my example [base image](https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/docker-base). The last step of my entrypoint script is to then use `gosu` to drop from root back to the user, now with the changed uid/gid, and all files written will now match those of the user on the host.

If you happen to be running on MacOS, a recent feature called [osxfs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/) automatically corrects for uid/gid mismatches with host volumes.

Comment: Your third option Is my preferred one. It seems the most portable to me. I found It could be quite slow to chown mounted volumes if there are a lot of files in It though.Have you experienced this too? How do you mitigate the extra time required by the entrypoint?

Comment: Fewer and smaller files in the image would be the only option I know to reduce the recursive chown time. Each chown is going to trigger a copy on write operation.